# How to display a backtrace for an Error thrown in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm currently debugging an algorithm I implemented in Haskell for my Diploma thesis. It seems to work correctly for most inputs, yet I found one input which makes GHC throw the error

> *** Exception: Map.find: element not in the map

Since I have many Map lookups in my code, I need to find the line throwing this error to make any sense of it. I read through [this guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html#ghci-debugger-exceptions), but although I set the flag `fbreak-on-exception` (and `-error`), all GHCi gives me after tracing the function I'm testing is:

```
[...]> :trace test
[...]
Stopped at <exception thrown>
_exception ::
  e = GHC.Exception.SomeException (GHC.Exception.D:Exception _
                                                         (GHC.Show.D:Show ...) ....)
                              (GHC.Exception.ErrorCall ['M',....])
Unable to list source for <exception thrown>
Try rerunning with :trace, :back then :list
[<exception thrown>] [...]> :history
Empty history. Perhaps you forgot to use :trace?
```

Trying `:trace` again doesn't seem to help either.

So, can someone tell me what is going wrong or offer another way of finding the offending line? Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm using GHC version 7.0.3, so the linked guide should apply.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595077/how-can-i-get-the-position-where-error-was-called) for a better solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this will help you

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Debugging

> LocH provides wrappers over assert for generating source-located exceptions and errors. 
>   ...
>   adding: `import Debug.Trace.Location` and then recompiling with the preprocessor on:
>
> ```
>   $ ghc A.hs --make -pgmF loch -F -no-recomp
>   [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( A.hs, A.o )
>   Linking A ...
>   $ ./A
>   A: A.hs:14:14-19: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
> ```

There are also other tips on the wiki, like e.g. using the [Safe-Library](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~ndm/safe/).

Comment: Thank you Hal!  
Unfortunately, Loch no longer seems to be supported, at least it doesn't compile on modern versions of GHC.  
But I will try the other methods in your Wiki link.

Comment: Okay, after looking at the Safe-Library, I replaced all instances of `Data.Map.(!)` with `findWithDefault (error "line nr")` and found the bug. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! :) I just found http://hackage.haskell.org/package/loch-th, which seems to build on GHC7.

Comment: Cool, I'll keep this in mind for those other bugs that will turn up. :)

Comment: Maybe Don Stewart can say some words about LocH, whether it will be maintained again or if he is looking for someone to maintain it for him? Seems like a great extension for Haskell programms.