# How can I get the position where error was called?

Tags: haskell

I am looking for something to replace [loch](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/loch) (and its preprocessor) since it doesn't compile with ghc 7.

Specifically, if `error` is called then I would like to figure out, as conveniently as possible, where it was called from (line number and stack trace would be nice).

Comment: You can't really control where or when other libraries use `error`, but my personal preference for my own code is to avoid `error` as much as possible. As general advice to anyone reading this, if you need to know why code is taking a particular branch of execution, *don't* use `error` to find a stack trace; the best way right now is probably `Debug.Trace`.

Comment: @DanBurton I don't think this applies to what I am asking for. Say that I execute my program and unexpectedly I get `*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list`, now I would like to know where the call to head that produced this error is in the source code.

Comment: I have a patch for ghc that adds that.  I need to merge it.

Comment: @HaskellElephant the solution to *that* would be to avoid functions that you know might throw an exception. It isn't a perfect solution -- there could always be code that you cannot inspect -- but it does solve most issues.

Comment: Consider using the GHCi debugger. [See my answer here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724434/how-to-debug-haskell-code).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `-xc` RTS option, as described on [this page](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html); you need to compile your program with profiling support, and the output is pretty ugly, but it works.

This should do it:

```
$ ghc --make -prof -auto-all myprog.hs
$ ./myprog +RTS -xc
```

Technically this only gives a *cost centre stack*, not a true stack trace. Improved stack trace support is [coming in GHC 7.4](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/mm68o/ghc_74_branched_whats_in_for_christmas/c324u0m?context=1).

Answer (score 5):

If this is for use in code you're working on, and you can tolerate using Template Haskell, [the `placeholders` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/placeholders) is a cute and simple way to do something like this. It won't help you find the location of actual `error` expressions, though, only uses of its own `error`-like functions.

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty trivial to get it to build with GHC-7. It's just the `Control.Exception` change that came with 6.12, the simple fix is to change the `Exception` type to `SomeException` in `Debug.Trace.Location`, line 70 and add an expression type signature in line 144. Restrict the `base` dependency to `>= 4.2 && < 4.6` in the .cabal file (bump the version) and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

A quick-n-dirty workaround is the [`assert`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Exception.html#g:15) function from Control.Exception. However, it's a little clunkier than `error`.

***Warning:** All asserts will be silently ignored if you compile with optimizations (`ghc -O1`, `-O2`, etc.).*

Example:

```
import Control.Exception

main = do
    print (42 + (assert True  17)) -- adds 42 and 17
    print (42 + (assert False 21)) -- crashes
```

Output:

```
59
test.hs: /tmp/test.hs:5:18-23: Assertion failed
```

Note the line number "5" in the output.

You could use `trace` from Debug.Trace to add an error message:

```
    print (42 + (trace "omg error" $ assert False 21))
```